# Running an app under specific locale "formats"

Tags: command-line, locale, localization

I know you can use
`export LANG=xx_XX.UTF8`
to run a program under specific locale, but regional settings in Linux/Ubuntu also feature "Formats" option.

Is there a way to run an app under specific `locale` and `formats` (en_US and en_GB respectively) for testing purposes, without affecting system-wise settings?

Follow-up question: how can I dump all ENV variables/setup under which the specific process is running?

Comment: Is it a GUI program? ... You can set the environment variable specifically and only for a certain program like e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 program` i.e. on the commandline itself directly before that program and **without** `export` ... Compare e.g. `LANG=ar_SA.UTF-8 gedit` (assuming Arabic Saudi Arabia locale is installed on your system) to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gedit`

Comment: Hello, yes, @Raffa this is a GUI program, hence the question. I know abut `LC_*` variables but as you said it wont work for GUI. Namely Firefox.

Comment: `LC_*` should equally work for all programs alike GUI or otherwise ... In fact any set `LC_*` should take precedence over `LANG` ... The reason I mentioned GUI is the fact that some GUI programs are independent and have their own internal locale settings that will override the set environment variables or even ignore them selectively and that is up to those programs developers  to decide with little that we can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to run an app under specific locale and formats (en_US
> and en_GB respectively) for testing purposes, without affecting
> system-wise settings?

Yes, you can set environment variables on the commandline itself before the program's name/command like `LANG` for example with `gedit`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 gedit
```

... and that will set that environment variable specifically and only for that certain program i.e `gedit` during that certain session/run ... However, the chosen language should be both supported by and installed for that certain program for this to work.

Other local/regional formats, however, can be explicitly set separately each has its own specific environment variable like for example `LC_MEASUREMENT`, `LC_TIME`, `LC_NUMERIC`, `LC_MONETARY` ... etc. and you can set as many of those as you need in the same way like for example:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8 gedit
```

> How can I dump all ENV variables/setup under which the specific
> process is running?

Assuming a currently running process ... That is in `/proc/PID/environ` where `PID` is the actual running process's ID.

Taking `gedit` as an example program, those can be dumped (*in Bash*) for example like so:

```
(gedit & disown) &>/dev/null; cat /proc/$(pgrep 'gedit')/environ
```

... those, however, are NUL/zero delimited entries and, **for readability**, you might want to parse them into separate lines by for example piping the output to `xargs` like so:

```
(gedit & disown) &>/dev/null; cat /proc/$(pgrep 'gedit')/environ |
xargs -0 -n1
```

**Notice** that while most commandline programs will honor all the explicitly set commandline locale environment variables and the global environment variables otherwise, this is not the case with GUI programs ... Simple GUI programs and DE shipped programs (like Gnome apps for example) will most likely honor those environment variable likewise, but more complex/independent programs like web-browsers for example will most likely have their own internal configuration files that are set inside their UI and will ignore external duplicate environment settings and accept others that are not internally set ...

As an example, the FireFox web-browser only accepts setting the user interface language from within its preferences menu in the UI and saves it as an entry called `intl.locale.requested` that will look something like `user_pref("intl.locale.requested", "en-US,ar");` and that is saved in a file called `prefs.js` inside the active profile's directory i.e. for the SNAP version that would be in `~/snap/firefox/common/.mozilla/firefox/0qag4e79.default/prefs.js` for example ... And therefore the `LANG` or `LANGUAGE` locale environment variables are ignored whether globally set or explicitly set on the commandline ... However, other locale related environment variables like `LC_MEASUREMENT`, `LC_TIME`, `LC_NUMERIC` and `LC_MONETARY` are still honored (in both cases) as it appears until now, so you can set those ones explicitly on the commandline if you wish and expect them to both be reflected in `/proc/PID/environ` and take effect as well when applicable.

Comment: What about GUI programs like Firefox? Will it honor/obey locale enforced?

Comment: @Digika Some will fully, some will partially and some won't ... I have updated the answer for that.